# Emacs - Line numbers are not displaying

Tags: emacs

I have `(setq global-linum-mode t)` in my .emacs and I enable line number mode with `M-x line-number-mode` but still there are no line numbers on the margin. What am I doing wrong? I am on OS X and Emacs v. 24.3.

Comment: `M-x linum-mode`  The modeline uses `line-number-mode`.  I prefer to disable global stuff and use mode hooks instead -- e.g., `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))`

Comment: @lawlist Thanks! `M-x linum-mode` works without adding the mode hook. Actually, would it be possible to turn the line numbering on only with `.clj` files. I see that `.clj` files open in `(Clojure Paredit Fill)` mode. I haven't tried it but can it be something like `(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))`

Comment: Yes, that is the advantage of removing the global stuff -- you can make it apply only to a specific mode.  Just comment out your `(setq global-linum-mode t)`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation for the variable `global-linum-mode` has the answer to your problem:

> Setting this variable directly does not take effect;
>   either customize it (see the info node `Easy Customization')
>   or call the function`global-linum-mode'.

So evaluating `(setq global-linum-mode t)` will *not* cause `linum-mode` to be turned on for all buffers. You would evaluate `(global-linum-mode)` to do that.

You are correct in your comment above that to turn on `linum-mode` only for certain modes you would evaluate `(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook linum-mode)` (using `clojure-mode` for example).